# Why is Firefox spawning multiple tabs instead of opening a website with puppeteer-core?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, puppeteer

I am trying to use Firefox with `puppeteer-core` to open a website. Instead of opening the desired website, Firefox opens 3 Tabs with unrelated URLs.

This is my node-js code:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath: 'firefox',
    headless: false
});

const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
}
)();
```

Instead of opening google.com, Firefox spawns 3 seperate tabs:

1. Tab 1 with the URL http://translate,backforwardcache,acceptchframe,mediarouter,optimizationhints/
2. Tab 2 with the URL http://idledetection/
3. Tab 3 with the URL http://srgb/

These terms all seem to be some kind of arguments for Firefox, but I have no idea why they appear.

Firefox should be supported based on this issue: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6796 .
When substituting `executablePath: 'firefox'` with `executablePath: 'google-chrome-stable'`, puppeteer works as expected, which means that the problem has to be with Firefox.

- Firefox version: `102.0`
- puppeteer-core version: `8.19.2`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding `product: "firefox"` to the launch options